# Is there any method to secure onnx file on app side?

Tags: security, mobile, onnx, cracking

I am using onnx file on mobile app. but I am wondering how to secure my onnx file on the app.
Is there any way to secure onnx file on mobile app?

I have tried to encrypt onnx and and decrypt if model needed to use. but this method is not secure as well because it can decoded as correct onnx content before usage.

Comment: This question is off-topic. Please read about what is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here and what questions you should [avoid asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).